# Using css in GWT with own classes

Tags: css, gwt

I have tinkered with GWT a menu that emphasizes the active, so much to hover the item.

This works quite well as long as I define any class for CSS. Since I have two menus here I would like to use CSS classes.

No matter how I now turn and turn and the classes used, it does not work.

Here, the functional implementation and possibly someone can tell me how I can now add the class "Item" . That these styles are applied only to elements with the class "Item", the class "active" to inherit the properties of the item. :)

I did it with active item: tries visited, but here seemingly no style is added to the element...

menuItem.ui.xml

```
<ui:style  type='de.hfu.wolke.client.MenuItem.MyStyle'>
.item:link,  .item:visited
{
padding: 0 20px;
background-color: #83B81A;
border-left:1px solid #83B81A;
border-bottom:1px solid #83B81A;
border-top:1px solid #83B81A;
border-right:1px solid white;
text-align: left;
text-decoration:none;
display: block;
float: left;
font: bold 12px Arial;
line-height: 26px;
color:white;
}
.item:hover, .item.active:visited, .item.acitve:link
{
background-color: white;
color: #83B81A;
border-left-color:white;
border-right-color:white;
}
</ui:style>
<g:HTMLPanel>
    <g:InlineHyperlink styleName="{style.item}" ui:field="itemLink"></g:InlineHyperlink> 
</g:HTMLPanel>
```

Appending the style "active"

```
  interface MyStyle extends CssResource {
        String active();
//      String item();
      }

public void activate(){
    itemLink.addStyleName(style.active());
}

public void deactivate(){
    itemLink.removeStyleName(style.active());

}
```

Thanks in advance. :)

EDIT: I am not sure what of the steps solved the Problem. 
First I simplified the Style by removing the "a"-tag. I thought the pseudoclasses are only working with it. ;-) 
Further I added the style of "item" directly in UIBinder and not in the constructor. Last but not least I used "addStyleName" and "removeStyleName" than "setStyleName". I thought "setStyleName". I guess this was the crucial solution.

Comment: Hi, I think you should try to write your question in english.

Comment: Oh damn! Thank you very much. I guess I am still not awake. :D

Comment: As André says, write the solution in your answer and don't 'fix' question, because it makes it difficult for others to see what was wrong and possible could have been of help for others with similar problems. BTW 1) setStyleName with the boolean argument uses {add,remove}StyleName internally. While without the boolean replaces the current styles, which means it would remove styles added. BTW 2) You have a typo in you ui.xml: `acitve:link`

Answer (score 0):

Try CssResource.ensureInjected().